# What is the use of SaveAsFile(fileName,Imageformat) method in the Selenium Screenshot class while taking screenshot?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to figure out the correct usage of the `SaveAsFile` methods in the selenium screenshot class, in my view both the methods we are passing the filename along with the file format(filename.png) or (filename.jpeg,ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg) to get the screenshot.

When do we need to use `SaveAsFile(filename.jpeg,ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg)` method? what it does while taking a screenshot?

```
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot) driver).GetScreenshot();
ss.SaveAsFile(@"E:\C#\MyFirstProject\MyFirstProject\Screenshot\Mytest.png");
ss.SaveAsFile(@"E:\C#\MyFirstProject\MyFirstProject\Screenshot\nataraj2.Jpeg", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the `SaveAsFile` method without a second argument uses `ScreenshotImageFormat.Png` by default. The other `SaveAsFile` with two arguments allows you to specify a broader set of options.

So you should use the `SaveAsFile(fileName, format)` method if you want to manually specify a file type.

Snippet source code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Saves the screenshot to a Portable Network Graphics (PNG) file, overwriting the
/// file if it already exists.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName">The full path and file name to save the screenshot to.</param>
public override void SaveAsFile(string fileName)
{
    this.SaveAsFile(fileName, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
}

/// <summary>
/// Saves the screenshot to a file, overwriting the file if it already exists.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName">The full path and file name to save the screenshot to.</param>
/// <param name="format">A <see cref="ScreenshotImageFormat"/> value indicating the format
/// to save the image to.</param>
public void SaveAsFile(string fileName, ScreenshotImageFormat format)
{
```

Source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/64447d4b03f6986337d1ca8d8b6476653570bcc1/dotnet/src/webdriver/Screenshot.cs

The `Image.Save` logic that selenium uses is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=net-5.0#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_). The Microsoft docs state the following behaviour:

> If no encoder exists for the file format of the image, the Portable Network Graphics (PNG) encoder is used. When you use the Save method to save a graphic image as a Windows Metafile Format (WMF) or Enhanced Metafile Format (EMF) file, the resulting file is saved as a Portable Network Graphics (PNG) file. This behavior occurs because the GDI+ component of the .NET Framework does not have an encoder that you can use to save files as .wmf or .emf files.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong,
There is no difference in the behavior, because both the methods we are giving the filename with extension. @MaartenDev

Comment: correct, same behaviour, the only difference is that `SaveAsFile(fileName)` uses the `ScreenshotImageFormat.Png` format by default. So if you write it to a Jpeg file you should use `SaveAsFile(fileName, ScreenshotImageFormat.Jpeg)`

Comment: Selenium uses the following method to write the image to a file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks, @MaartenDev.  SaveAsFile(fileName) default format is .Png but even we give any other format like .Jpeg or .wmf  also works.
`ss.SaveAsFile(@"E:\C#\MyFirstProject\MyFirstProject\Screenshot\Mytest2.wmf");`

Comment: Ah nice, that is also documented in the microsoft side, I updated the answer